# Set Date to jquery flipCountDown

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Maybe this question is already mentioned before, but I tried all possible ways to add specific date into the code, but it doesn't work.

I'm using **jquery.flipCountDown** from this [link](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/flipcountdown/)

Here is my code:

```
<span id="expired"> </span>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
  var dt = new Date();
  jQuery('#expired').flipcountdown({  
size:'md',
beforeDateTime: '1/01/' + (dt.getFullYear() + 1) + ' 00:00:01'
  });
});
</script>
```

I want to change above code to something that I'll be able to add specific date into the code with format: **`Y-m-d`** to make count down.

**For example:**  2017-03-18   How to add this date into code to make it count down?

I highly appreciate your help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try giving it a `Date` object, like `var dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1);` then `beforeDateTime: dt`.

Comment: Still I didn't get how to add a date into code.